# batch windows cd not working when multiple cmd autoload running

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I'm starting with batch on windows. I want to set some alias and persist them and also set start configurations, etc. when I open the cmd.

I found that windows when start a new cmd instance looks for a regedit variable under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor path and get the value of AutoRun key.

That is working fine, I defined an alias.cmd file and set up all my DOSKEY.
Perfect! But now I want to add more files, like startup.cmd that change my start directory. For example E:\

I'm adding some images to reference my explanation.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

The big problem is that when I run my startup.cmd and run the cd /d E:\ command nothing happens, but the file is read (tried with the @echo prompt).

What is wrong? If literally copy and paste cd /d E:\ after my terminal opens it works... Also, if I try in this cmd files use the alias just declared nothing works as well.

Edit:
I tried with different AutoRun type and `,;|` delimiters and still not working.

[image]

Comment: I have never had the need to use the `AutoRun` value in that manner, but find it difficult to understand how piping the output from `E:\cmd_scripts\alias.cmd`, _(which incidentally appears to output nothing)_, into `E:\cmd_scripts\startup.cmd`, _(which incidentally appears not to accept intput)_, can achieve anything along the lines of what you're expecting.

Comment: @Compo I don't know, I tried with ; and , but with these didn't work... i just want to run both files. Reference to https://superuser.com/questions/1239166/how-to-add-multiple-data-to-one-string-value-in-regedit

Comment: I'd stick with **one** autorun and if neccessary call other batches from that. For easier maintenance I'd store the aliases in a seperate file and load with `Doskey /MACROFILE=yourfile.txt`

Comment: @LotPings Can't be done with multi value in regedit? I will try this approach too

Comment: It very likely doesn't accept multiple files, only a command line or a batch file, _(containing commands)_, not a series of files! The value is either `REG_SZ` or `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, not `REG_MULTI_SZ`.

Comment: @Compo I tried with `REG_SZ` `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and `REG_MULTI_SZ` and also trying , ; and | delimiters.

Comment: @Raikish, stop wasting time trying, I've already told you that `AutoRun` doesn't accept multiple batch files!

Comment: @Compo Okay thank you Compo, I will try the approach of creating the.cmd and calling the other ones from that.